# Weird Value Error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"634”'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Invalid literal usually occurs when the string cannot be parsed to an integer. But this error is weird. I got this while using pyspark.
The code is given below

```
%pyspark
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from datetime import datetime
lines = sc.textFile("s3://citibike-nyc/nyc-bike-data/FinalMerge.csv")
def mk_int(s):
    s = s.strip()


    return int(s) if s else 0


# Each line is converted to a tuple.
header = lines.first()
data = lines.filter(lambda l: l!=header)
data=data.map(lambda l:l.split(","))
trip_data = data.map(lambda p: (mk_int(p[0]),datetime.strptime (p[1],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),datetime.strptime (p[2],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),mk_int(p[3]),p[4].strip(),float(p[5]),float(p[6]),mk_int(p[7]),p[8].strip(), float(p[9]),float(p[10]),int(p[11]),p[12].strip(),mk_int(p[13]),mk_int(p[14])))
trip_data.take(1)
```

for which I got the ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"634”'
What is wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you've got quotes in your string, one regular and one curly.

Comment: Oops, you are correct. Thank you, soo much. So I should use replace to get rid of it I believe?

Comment: That should work.